# Format main Windows drive and install openSUSE, leave additional drive intact

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, opensuse

I have an old laptop which has two 256 GB HDDs. On Windows, these are the C: and D: drives. Windows is installed on C:, and D: is used for additional data.

I'd like to turn this into an SSH server. I want to format the C: drive, and install Linux on it. I'm planning to use openSUSE 15.0. This is straightforward, but I'm concerned about what will happen to the D: drive. I need to maintain access to it as an external drive, since it contains all my files.

On the openSUSE installer documentation, it says: "In case it contains more than a single hard disk, you may choose which disk(s) to use and where to place the root partition. If the disk(s) already contain partitions, decide whether to remove or resize them." So I can pick the C: drive, remove its existing partitions, and mount the root partition there. I just want to know what will happen to the D: drive after I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are careful to select the correct disk during the installation it is perfectly safe to leave it in during the installation, but if both disks are the same size/make/model it can be tricky to determine which one is the right one.
And in a laptop it is not always a given that C: is the first disk and D: the second one. Furthermore Windows may actually boot from one disk and have C: on the other drive.

Just temporarily disconnect the disk (or disable it in BIOS if you have that option).
That way you can be certain the SUSE installation won't see it.
After the setup reconnect the disk and mount it in SUSE.

This is the safest way to go.  No chance of accidentally messing up the data disk.